# No me deja pasar de String a Calendar

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion de gestion de bibliotecas y estoy atascado en el metodo que devuelve una fecha. Estoy tratando de insertarlo en un objeto Calendar pero no hay manera. A ver si me podeis echar una mano y decirme donde estoy fallando. Os paso el codigo:

```
public Calendar dame_fecha(String dia, String mes, String anio) {
        Calendar fecha_prestamo=Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formato=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
        int d=Integer.valueOf(dia);
        int m=Integer.valueOf(mes);
        int a=Integer.valueOf(anio);
        fecha_prestamo.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
        fecha_prestamo.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
        fecha_prestamo.set(Calendar.YEAR, a);
        fecha_prestamo.setTime(formato.parse("dd/MM/YYYY"));
        return fech_prestamo=fecha_prestamo.getTime();
    }
```

En el return me da error de que no se puede pasar de String a Calendar.

Comment: Si si, Java. Se me paso ponerlo.

Comment: La última sentencia no tiene mucho sentido. En un return no se hacen asignaciones, simplemente se devuelve el valor de una expresión. En tu caso `fecha_prestamo` ya es es un `Calendar`, que es lo que se espera que devuelva la función por lo que te valdría con poner `return fecha_prestamo;`

Comment: Vaya, pues va a ser eso! Muchisimas gracias!! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando el código observo algunos puntos que no se si te faltan claridad en ellos o que.

1. sonart te recomienda qe en ves de hacer uso del **Integer.valueOf** uses el parseo ya que con este será más claro y eficiente la conversión, reemplaza

> Integer.valueOf(variable_string)

por

> Integer.parseInt(variable_string)

2. Observo que haces uso del **SimpleDateFormat** le das un formato a la instancia de la siguiente manera "dd/MM/YYYY", ten presente lo siguiente, esto es tomado de las correcciones que hace sonart:

*El año de la semana ("YYYY") no debe usarse para formatear la fecha.
Pocos desarrolladores son conscientes de la diferencia entre Y para el "año de la semana" y y para el año al formatear y analizar una fecha con SimpleDateFormat. Es probable que esto se deba a que para la mayoría de las fechas, el año de la semana y el año son iguales, por lo que las pruebas en cualquier momento que no sea la primera o la última semana del año arrojarán el mismo valor para y e Y. Pero en la última semana de diciembre y el primera semana de enero, puede obtener resultados inesperados.*

Puedes leer un poco más sobre esto en el siguiente enlace: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year

3. Después de crear tu variable formato de tipo SimpleDateFormat, realizas un parseo de fechas es decir de un String a un Date, como lo expresa la siguiente linea:

> formato.parse("dd/MM/YYYY")

Has realizado esto pero al ejecutarlo sería un error ya que es imposible convertir a una fecha los caracteres que has pasado en el parámetro. Si deseas transformar a Date los parámetros que recibe tu función **dame_fecha** entonces realiza lo siguiente:

> formato.parse(dia + "/" + mes + "/" + anio)

4. Al final de la función **dame_fecha** cuando se realiza el retorno, realizas una asignación, no se si aquella variable es la que localmente llamas y creaste de tipo **Calendar** o estás asignandole un valor a una variable global en tu clase que llame **fech_prestamo**. De ser el caso que intentas asignarle un nuevo valor a tu variable local, tienes un error tipográfico en tu variable y por otro lado no puedes hacer una asignación de tipo Date a un tipo Calendar.

Si es el caso de que usas una variable global, no lo dejes en el return ya que la función dame_feha retorna un Calendar, y allí estás haciendo que retorne tu variable global la cual es un tipo date.

te adjunto un ejemplo de tu código corregido. Haciendo uso de la variable final como global.

> import java.text.ParseException;
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
> import java.util.Calendar;
> import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

```
private static Date fech_prestamo;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println(dame_fecha("18", "12", "2020"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Calendar dame_fecha(String dia, String mes, String anio) throws ParseException {
    Calendar fechaPrestamo = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");          // "dd/MM/YYYY"
    int d = Integer.parseInt(dia);                                          // Integer.valueOf(dia)
    int m = Integer.parseInt(mes);                                          // Integer.valueOf(mes)
    int a = Integer.parseInt(anio);                                         // Integer.valueOf(anio)
    fechaPrestamo.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
    fechaPrestamo.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
    fechaPrestamo.set(Calendar.YEAR, a);
    fechaPrestamo.setTime(formato.parse(dia + "/" + mes + "/" + anio));     // "dd/MM/YYYY"
    fech_prestamo = fechaPrestamo.getTime();

    return fechaPrestamo;
}
```

}

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Tu método devuelve un `Calendar`, sin embargo, al hacer `fecha_prestamo.getTime()`, lo que haces es devolver un objeto de la clase `Date`.
Puedes consultar los tipos de retorno de los métodos de calendar [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), donde pone "Method Summary".

Sugiero que devuelvas `fecha_prestamo` a secas y luego le hagas el `getTime()` en otro método, o que cambies el tipo de retorno de la función `dame_fecha`  de tipo `Calendar` a tipo `Date`.